# How to Properly Raise Errors From Class

Tags: class, error-handling, scope, vb6

My question is: how do I properly raise errors within a class so that the caller which is instantiating that class can use proper error handling techniques?

I'm upgrading old VB6 spaghetti code that didn't use classes . In the past I always made use of ***On Error Resume Next*** and ***On Error Goto myLabel*** to deal with errors when alternatives weren't any cleaner for my code.

However, I can't get the caller to handle errors because if I raise an error within a method or a property of my class the error raises regardless of whether I used ***On Error*** statement to catch it from the caller. A sample code would be something like this:

MyClass:

```
Public Sub Bar()
    If valid Then
        'some code here
    Else
        Err.Raise 5
    End if
End Sub
```

MainForm:

```
Private Sub CallFoo()
    Dim foo as New MyClass

    On Error Goto fooliure 'Starts ignoring errors
    Call foo.Bar() 'Program stops with an exception
    On Error Goto 0 'Ends error handling

    Exit Sub
    fooliure:
        'Error handling code
End Sub
```

Also Microsoft says that this is how they intended the Error handling to be performed in VB 6.0 as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973849.aspx).

At this point I'm considering using an object within my class that would collect errors that can be retrieved by the caller. If I can avoid going that way I will, but I've had no luck so far finding an answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking but if this is happening during debugging you need to change the error handling settings in Project Properties (IIRC).

Comment: I agree with @spodger.  Specifically, go into Tools|Options|General|Error Trapping and make sure `Break on Unhandled Errors` is selected.

Comment: @BrianMStafford - thanks, I couldn't remember the exact location!

Comment: Are you saying that the "fooliure" label is not being reached once Bar() is called?

Comment: @DaveInCaz the error is never catched. So far for me it only catches errors in the local scope and/or code in modules.

Comment: @spodger thanks I'm going to test that, and see how it works.

Comment: Indeed the solution by spoder and Brian worked. Also I tried to compile and the compiled program actually captures the error even without changing the setting (probably because the setting only affects the debugger). Anyway this will make debugging much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David, here is a short tutorial on VBA error handling 101.

- `Err` object. This is a singleton object that holds the current error. Do not try to instantiate this object (i.e. don't use `Set objErr = New Err` -- this will fail)
- `On Error` - set error handling. Possible error handlers:

  - `On Error GoTo Label` - Execution jumps to `Label` when an error is encountered
  - `On Error Resume Next` - Execution jumps to the next line when an error is encountered
  - `On Error GoTo 0` - Turns off current error handler. Any subsequent errors will be handled by the caller
  - `On Error Resume` - Execution jumps to the line that caused the error (not recommended)
- The `Err` object is cleared (loses the current error) when:

  - A subroutine, function or property is called
  - A subroutine, function or property exits normally
  - An `On Error` statement is executed
  - `Err.Clear` clears the current error when called
- Raising exceptions. You can raise errors any time you need to. Canonical form:

  ```
  Err.Raise 1001 + vbObjectError, Description:="An exception occurred."
  ```
- Custom errors: use `vbObjectError` to make a user-defined error. Example:

  - `1001 + vbObjectError`
  - The integer range is from 0 to 65535
- Error handling sequence:

  1. If there is a local error handler defined in the routine, executes it
  2. If there is no local handler, raises the error to the caller
  3. If the caller has no handler, keeps raising the error until a local handler is found
  4. If there is no top-level handler, the application terminates
- Creating error chains. It is very useful to create error chains that show the originating error, and display the list of routines on the stack when the error occurred. To do this:

  - Add error handling to *every* routine that could possibly cause an error
  - Always re-raise the error to the caller
  - Add a string to `Err.Source` naming the routine when re-raising the error
  - The top-level calling routine can use `MsgBox` to inform the user of the error (or other logging can be implemented)

Here is a code example demonstrating these ideas:

```
Public Sub TestErrorLevel1()

    On Error GoTo HandleErr ' clears Err object

    TestErrorLevel2

    Exit Sub

HandleErr:
    ' top-level error handler -- nothing else to raise error to
    ' show error and complete call chain
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf _
        & "Source: modTest.TestErrorLevel1" & vbCrLf & Err.Source
End Sub

Public Sub TestErrorLevel2()

    On Error GoTo HandleErr ' clears Err object

    TestErrorLevel3

    Exit Sub

HandleErr:
    ' re-raise error, adding this subroutine to call chain
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "modTest.TestErrorLevel2" & vbCrLf & Err.Source, Err.Description
End Sub

Public Sub TestErrorLevel3()

    On Error GoTo HandleErr ' clears Err object

    Err.Raise 1001 + vbObjectError, Description:="User-defined error. Offset range from 0 to 65535"

    Exit Sub

HandleErr:
    ' re-raise: add module and routine to originating error
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "modTest.TestErrorLevel3" & vbCrLf & Err.Source, Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a very neat example. So going a bit further, do you think it is a good idea to encapsulate an error list in an enumeration in a module and with helper function to call err.raise?

Something like:
`Call RaiseError(USER_DEFINED1)`

Module would contain an Enum with USER_DEFINED1 assigned with <_some number_> + vbObjectError and obviously a function named RaiseError which would actually call Err.Raise.

Edit: formatting

Comment: Yes, I think that is a good idea. I do basically that with an error handling module that I wrote. Done properly, it can save a lot of repetitive typing, and makes the routines easier to read. This also lets you transparently add error logging when required.